# Create only those users from a list that do not exist

Tags: ansible

I have a list of users and I only want to create those, which do not exist on the system.

This is what I have tried:

```yaml
- name: Connection to Unix server
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    USER_ID_details:
      - user_id: my_user1
        groups: wheel
        real_full_name: my_user_name1
        affected_host: localhost
        email_id: my_user1@ibm.com
      - user_id: my_user2
        groups: wheel
        real_full_name: my_user_name2
        affected_host: localhost
        email_id: my_user2@ibm.com
  tasks:
    - name: check for the ID is present
      #shell: "id {{ item.user_id }}"
      shell: grep "{{ item.user_id }}" /etc/passwd | awk -F":" '{print $1}'
      loop: "{{ USER_ID_details }}"
      ignore_errors: true
      register: id_check

    - name: setting var
      set_fact:
        user_id_names1: "{{ user_id_names1|default([]) + [item.stdout] }}"
      with_items: "{{ id_check.results }}"
     when: item.stdout != ""

    - debug: var=user_id_names1

    - block:
        - name: create Linux user as per specification
          user:
            name: "{{ item.user_id }}"
            password: "{{ pass_reg.stdout_lines[0] | password_hash('sha512') }}"
            group: "{{ group_name }}"
            groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
            comment: "{{ comment }}"
            shell: "{{ user_shell }}"
            #uid: "{{ uid_num.item }}"
            home: "/home/{{ item.user_id}}"
          loop: "{{ USER_ID_details }}"
          when:
            - os_type == "RedHat"
            - "{{ item.user_id }} not {{id_check.results}}"
```

What could be the best way to check if user exists, and only add those, that don't exist on server. I'm trying to check the `user_id_names1` list of ids generated against list dictionary `USER_ID_details` and filter the existing ones.

Comment: See [getent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html#ansible-builtin-getent-a-wrapper-to-the-unix-getent-utility). But, Ansible modules are idempotent (in most cases), i.e. there is no point in testing whether a user exists or not. The result of the module [user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#ansible-builtin-user-manage-user-accounts) will be the existence of the account if *state=present* (default). The condition in your code is redundant. The module *user* will not run if the user exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vladimir Botka stated on the comment, ansible does that already. Most modules (including the `user` module) will ensure that the state you specify will be present on the machine, after ansible ran.
For example, if you specify that a certain user exists on the system, it will after you ran the playbook. It will be created if it didn't exist before, but it will not be added, if it already existed.

The catch is, that ansible will try to create the state you specified, possibly changing your existing users.
For example, let's assume your user already exists, but has changed the default `shell` to `/bin/zsh` while in your playbook you specify, that it should have `/bin/bash`. In that case, ansible will change the default `shell` to `/bin/bash` whenever you run your playbook.

If you don't care about existing users being modified (or you are sure they never will be) you can just run the `user` module for all users every time, as users will not be added twice.
Otherwise you can do this to check if a user exists and only add it if it does not:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: get list of existing users
    getent:
      database: passwd

  - name: get list of existing usernames
    set_fact:
      existing_users: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_passwd.keys() | list }}"

  - name: create Linux user as per specification
    user:
      name: "{{ item.user_id }}"
      password: "{{ pass_reg.stdout_lines[0] | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      group: "{{ group_name }}"
      groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
      comment: "{{ comment }}"
      shell: "{{ user_shell }}"
      home: "/home/{{ item.user_id}}"
    loop: "{{ USER_ID_details }}"
    when: item.user_id not in existing_users
```

Make sure to read the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html) of the `user` module and that you understand what all the options do.
For example, the `password` option will set the password of that user to the specified value. If the user changed his password, you will change it back every time you run the playbook. Set `update_password: on_create` to prevent that.
You are also setting the primary group of all users to the same value (in `group_name`). Make sure that is what you actually want to do.

Comment: Great, Thank you so much for your reply. yes, needed to completely avoid the tasks for id's which existed. So the above method is perfect. I also tried the below method which is similar

Answer (score 0):

@toydarian Used below method too when i didnot know about the getent option.

```
- name: check for the ID is present
  #shell: "id {{ item.user_id }}"
  shell: grep "{{ item.user_id }}" /etc/passwd | awk -F":" '{print $1}'
  loop: "{{ USER_ID_details }}"
  ignore_errors: true
  register: id_check

- name: setting var
  set_fact:
    user_id_names1: "{{ user_id_names1|default([]) + [item.stdout] }}"
  with_items: "{{ id_check.results }}"
  when: item.stdout != ""

- debug: var=user_id_names1


- name: create Linux user as per specification
  user:
    name: "{{ item.user_id }}"
    password: "{{ pass_reg.stdout_lines[0] | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    group: "{{ group_name }}"
    groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
    comment: "{{ item.real_full_name }}"
    shell: "{{ user_shell }}"
    #uid: "{{ uid_num.item }}"
    home: "/home/{{ item.user_id}}"
  loop: "{{ USER_ID_details }}"
  when:
    - os_type == "RedHat"
    - item.user_id not in user_id_names1
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same as the code in my answer. The only difference is, that you parse `/etc/passwd` manually using the `shell` module (which is what `getent` does) so you can keep using that, if you want. But as ansible has an inbuilt way to do it, I'd suggest using it. You should only use the `shell` module, if there is not "ansible-way" to do what you need.

Comment: Yes, i agree! better to use available ansible-way always if available